# tablespace show as null in pg_tables

Tags: postgresql

I have created table by passing tablespace name explicitly. But while checking in pg_tables and other pg_ tables

```
Create table test1c (Id integer, name varchar(10)) tablespace testts;

select * 
from pg_tables 
where tablename='test1c';
```

It should show tablespace name but showing it as null

Comment: Is `testts` maybe your default tablespace for the database?

Comment: yes  testts is default tablespace for this database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default tablespace will not show up in `pg_tables.tablespace`

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html)

> Name of tablespace containing table (**null if default for database**)

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

---

If you want to see the actual tablespace you need to include `pg_database` in the query:

```
select t.schemaname, t.tablename, 
       coalesce(t.tablespace, ts.default_tablespace) as tablespace
from pg_tables t
  cross join (
     select ts.spcname as default_tablespace
     from pg_database d
       join pg_tablespace ts on ts.oid = d.dattablespace
      where d.datname = current_database()
   ) ts
where tablename = 'test1c'
  and schemaname = 'public';
```